# Lambda to loop function through elements in list

Tags: python, pandas, function, pdf, lambda

How could I adjust this code to have the function loop through the list `models_2`? If I have the function use `models` it works, if I change to `models_2' it give me this error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seek'

This is my dataframe, from an excel with all cell format set to "text".

```
        MOD1       MOD2       MOD3       MOD4
0  File1.pdf  File3.pdf  File1.pdf  File3.pdf
1  File2.pdf        NaN  File2.pdf  File3.pdf
2  File3.pdf        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

```
models = ['MOD1']
models_2 = ['MOD1', 'MOD2']

def merge_pdf(models):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for name in models:
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                merger.append(row[name])
    merger.write(f"Order #XXXXXXX ({name}) Production Package - Rev.0.pdf")
    merger.close()

merge_pdf(models)
```

The full error message:

```
PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [_reader.py:1065]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\PyCharm\Excel_Reader\Excel_Reader.py", line 30, in <module>
    merge_pdf(models)
  File "Z:\PyCharm\Excel_Reader\Excel_Reader.py", line 27, in merge_pdf
    merger.append(row[name])
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 227, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 149, in merge
    pdfr = PdfFileReader(
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 239, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 911, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Comment: Your funciton does not use `models` anywhere in the code. On the other hand, it uses some variable `df` not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Steve Ah, missed a line, it's been edited in.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that says `seek`. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: My best guess is that the code tries to use `NaN` as a file name, which cannot work (it is a special floating-point value, not a string).

Comment: I edited in the full error message. how would I adjust `for index, row in df.iterrows():` to exclude the 'NaN'? Those are blank cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing because the column 'MOD2' contains `NaN` values, which are of type `float`. The way you handle this depends on what you want to do with those `NaN` values.

You can verify that by running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'MOD1':['File1.pdf', 'File2.pdf', 'File3.pdf'],
    'MOD2':['File1.pdf', np.nan, np.nan],
    'MOD3':['File1.pdf', 'File2.pdf', np.nan],
    'MOD4':['File1.pdf', 'File2.pdf', np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

models = ['MOD1']
models_2 = ['MOD1', 'MOD2']

merger = []

for name in models_2:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print(name, index, row[name], type(row[name]))
```

This will print the following:

```
MOD1 0 File1.pdf <class 'str'>
MOD1 1 File2.pdf <class 'str'>
MOD1 2 File3.pdf <class 'str'>
MOD2 0 File1.pdf <class 'str'>
MOD2 1 nan <class 'float'>
MOD2 2 nan <class 'float'>
```

If you know you only want to include the cells with string values, you can add a type check prior to appending it to your `merger` object, like so:

```
models = ['MOD1']
models_2 = ['MOD1', 'MOD2']

def merge_pdf(models):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for name in models:
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                if type(row[name]) == str:
                    merger.append(row[name])
    merger.write(f"Order #XXXXXXX ({name}) Production Package - Rev.0.pdf")
    merger.close()

merge_pdf(models)
```

Comment: This is closer! However now it is only doing the merge for the last element in `models_2`, it also appends files not in the column, for instance it's appending 6 files when it should be just 1 for `MOD2`.

Comment: I think it may be related to the indenting of the `merger.write....`

Comment: I think you nailed it. Indent that line three tabs and include it below the`if type(row[name]) == str:` line and it'll write each string name.